# Agendar tarefa linux (Cron)

Tags: linux, cron

Como abrir um arquivo e desligar o computador com o crontab?

Segue minha tentativa:

```
30 07 * * * killall qbittorrent (funcionando)
50 07 * * * shutdown -r 1 "Desligando desktop" (não funciona)
30 12 * * * qbittorrent & (não funciona)
55 13 * * * killall qbittorrent (funcioando)
08 20 * * * qbittorrent & (não funciona)
```

Comment: Já tentou assim 30 23 * * * root shutdown -h now?

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella já Feb 12 16:13:01 magneto CRON[9147]: (root) CMD (shutdown -h now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os seguintes comandos funcionaram para mim (utilizei `firefox` no lugar de `qbittorrent` porque não tenho `qbittorrent` instalado):

```
$ sudo su
```

para logar como root e **não** alterar a tabela crontab global (localizada em `/etc/crontab`).

```
$ crontab -e
```

para alterar a crontab do usuário root, com as seguintes entradas:

```
29 * * * * killall firefox
30 * * * * sudo shutdown -r now
35 * * * * su USUARIO -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox"
36 * * * * killall firefox
37 * * * * su USUARIO -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox"
```

Onde `USUARIO` pode ser qualquer usuário do seu sistema com o qual você queria executar o comando.

Acredito que seu comando só não estava funcionando porque `$DISPLAY` não estava definido, e o programa `cron` não entende nada de exibir coisas na tela.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Obrigado.